# In ruby / rails how do I make this helper for a common loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I write this bit of code all the time, it compaires two of the same array expect if they're the same item:

```
items.each_with_index do | x, i |
    items.each do | y, j |
        if x.id != y.id
            #... do some things
        end
    end
end
```

What I'd really like to write is:

```
items.compare_each do | x, y, i, j |
    #... do some things
end
```

How would you go about writing a helper that in ruby/rails? Or even does it already exist?

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? What is `items` and how are you using that loop?

Comment: I only see one array, `items` ... is the loop usually for a single array?

Comment: Items is just a any set of records, but they all have an id. Yes, sorry, it is compaing the same array to itself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to compare each element in a single array with every other element in that array, as your example code shows (rather than comparing two arrays with each other, as your text states), you want [`Array#combination`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-combination), possibly in conjunction with [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) if the indexing is important:

```
%i{a b c d e}.each_with_index.to_a.combination(2) {|(x,i),(y,j)| p [x,y,i,j] }
[:a, :b, 0, 1]
[:a, :c, 0, 2]
[:a, :d, 0, 3]
[:a, :e, 0, 4]
[:b, :c, 1, 2]
[:b, :d, 1, 3]
[:b, :e, 1, 4]
[:c, :d, 2, 3]
[:c, :e, 2, 4]
[:d, :e, 3, 4]
=> [[:a, 0], [:b, 1], [:c, 2], [:d, 3], [:e, 4]]
```

The above example also makes use of [argument destructuring](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).